# Egrep Help; how to extract rows out of a file

Tags: linux

Hello I don't know how to use egrep that well yet.

How do I extract rows out of a file to a new file matching a string like "icloud".

This is my bottleneck, cheers

Comment: (1) You don't know how to use ``egrep`` ***that well*** yet.  How well do you know it?  Do you know how to extract rows out of a file matching a string like "icloud" and display them to the terminal screen?  (2) Do you know how to write the output of a command to a file? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Question-askers are expected to do some independent research before posting a question.  The question should then explain what part(s) you understand and where you are stuck. … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
egrep "icloud" input.file > newFile
```

This copies all lines that contain the string "icloud" to the output file `newFile`.

---

If you want to extract the lines that *only* contain this string value (and nothing else), use

```
egrep "^icloud$" input.file > newFile
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
awk -F'\t' '$1 ~ /@aol/' < inputfile > outputfile
```